# How to Verify Contract Address Ownership on BscScan Using Gnosis Multisig

Tags: bsc, gnosis-safe

We own a multi-sig wallet with Gnosis and we are trying to Verify Contract Address Ownership on BscScan and we need some guidance. There are no instructions on how to do so from what we have researched. When I attempt to connect to Web3, it attempts to connect to my wallet my Metamask address instead of the Gnosis Safe Wallet Address

Comment: the ownership of the wallet contract?
idk what are you trying to do but check those links https://medium.com/@Deam/verifying-a-contract-triggered-by-another-contract-on-etherscan-io-96a8c5a0ac2

Comment: https://medium.com/giveth/verifying-gnosis-multisig-contract-on-etherscan-io-c87dcb32893c

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it seems Etherscan only supports in-browser wallets, and therefore it's impossible to connect the Safe.

Secondly, when you verify the ownership on etherscan, what happens under the hood is that you create an ECDSA signature for a message defined by etherscan. This is not possible with the Safe because to generate a signature, the account has to possess a private key, but the Safe is a smart contract wallet that is operated by code deployed on the Ethereum blockchain.